# Nginx - Exclude specific file or folder from logging to access.log

Tags: logging, nginx

I'm using an access and error log in Nginx.

I have extremely large number of requests for stats which take up too much storage space in access.log and are not required.

Is it possible to exclude a specific file or folder from logging to access.log?

I would like to exclude all requests to `/stats/`

```
server {
    listen  80 default_server;
    listen  443 ssl default_server;
    server_name ***.co.uk www.***.co.uk;

    root  /var/www/***/html;
    index index.html index.php;

    access_log /var/www/***/log/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/***/log/error.log;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this if you know which location block or server is handling the request for stats. Just add the directive `access_log off;` to the server or location block in which you want this disabled.

**--Edit--**

Add this location to your server block:

```
location /stats/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    access_log off;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question with a little more detail. How would I exclude the `stats` folder in this example?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check that it works. If not, let me know what the outcome was.

Comment: I found that defining the access log in the server block and then attempting to override it in the location block made no difference. I had to define different access log rules in each location block.